# If $A$ is a normal matrix with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ equals its algebraic multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am trying to solve the following question:

> If $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times m}$ is a normal matrix with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ equals its algebraic multiplicity.

I've nearly solved it, but I am having trouble arguing the last part. My proof goes as follows:

Since $A$ is square it has a Schur decomposition $A = Q T Q^*$ where $Q$ is unitary and $T$ is triangular. Since $A$ is normal, $T$ is normal. Now normal + triangular $\implies$ diagonal, so $A$ is unitarily diagonalizable as $A = Q T Q^*$.

**Part I'm having trouble with:**

I know that from here the conclusion should be pretty obvious, but I'm having trouble writing a formal argument. I've written one below, but it's long, wordy, and informal. On the exam, I would have 5 minutes at the very most to answer this question.

---

Let $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n$ be the distinct eigenvalues of $A$ with algebraic multiplicities $a_1, ..., a_n$, and geometric multiplicities $g_1, ..., g_n$.

Partition $Q$ as $(q_1 ... q_m).$ From the equation $A(q_1 ... q_m) = (q_1 ... q_m)T$ it is clear that the diagonal entries of $T$ are eigenvalues of $A$. Let $j_1, j_2, ..., j_m$ be the number of times that $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n$ appear in $diag(T)$, respectively.

Suppose that some eigenvalue $\lambda_k$ appears less than $a_k$ times in $diag(T)$. Now since
$$\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i = m = \sum_{i=1}^n j_i$$
if $j_k < a_k$ for some $k$, then $j_r > a_r$ for some $r$, so $\lambda_r$ which appears more than $r$ times in $diag(T)$. Look at the columns of $Q$ with the same indices as the indices of $\lambda_r$ in $diag(T)$. These columns are in the eigenspace of $\lambda_r$, but there are more than $a_r \ge g_r$ of them, so they must be dependent. However, this contradicts the fact that $Q$ is unitary.

Therefore for every $k$, we have $j_k \ge a_k$, so by looking at corresponding columns of $Q$, for every $k$ we have at least $a_k$ independent eigenvectors of $\lambda_k$, and since we also have at most $a_k$ of them, we have precisely $a_k$ of them. Thus for all $k$ $a_k = g_k$.

**EDIT:** Following a suggestion in the comments, I have written the proof for diagonal matrices.

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times m}$ is normal. By part $A$ it has a Schur factorization $A = QDQ^*$ where $D$ is upper triangular. Now $A^*A = QD^*DQ^* = AA^* = QDD^*Q^*$, so $D^*D = DD^*$, thus $D$ is normal and triangular, so it is diagonal. Now $A$ is similar to $D$, so their eigenvalues are the same, and have the same algebraic and geometric multiplicities. Now, let $d_1, ..., d_m$ be the diagonal elements of $D$. The characteristic polynomial of $D$ is $p(\lambda) = \Pi_{1 \le j \le m}(\lambda - \lambda_j)$, so the $d_j$ are eigenvalues, and the algebraic multiplicity of $d_j$ is the number of times it appears on the diagonal of $D$. Now if $d_j$ appears in columns with indices $a_1, ... a_r$ of $D$, then the vectors $e_{a_1}, ..., e_{a_r}$ are independent eigenvectors corresponding to $d_j$. Since in general geometric multiplicity $\le$ algebraic multiplicity, we have in this case that geometric multiplicity $=$ algebraic multiplicity.

Comment: What is $P$? Separately, it may be possible to write a simpler proof by first establishing that the geometric and algebraic multiplicities of any eigenvalue of $A$ must correspond with those of $T$. In other words, $A$ being normal reduces the proposition to establishing it for all diagonal matrices. And as you note above, somewhat indirectly, it's clearer to establish that for diagonal matrices, both the geometric and algebraic multiplicities of an eigenvalue $\lambda$ are simply the number of times $\lambda$ appears on the diagonal.

Comment: @leslietownes I'm so sorry, I wrote $P$ instead of $Q$. So do you mean something like: "$A$ is similar to the diagonal matrix $D$, and similar matrices have the same eigenvalues with the same algebraic and geometric multiplicities, so we will prove that for a diagonal matrix $D$, all the geometric multiplicities are equal to their respective algebraic multiplicities ..."?

Comment: exactly (assuming the details of that first part of that quoted sentence is assumed known). In my view, the point of the exercise is to notice that in the case of diagonal matrices, the proof is fairly straightforward.

Comment: @leslietownes Thank you so much! I will give it a try.

Comment: @leslietownes Hello again! If you don't mind, could you take a look at the question again? I've added a proof for diagonal matrices. I'm just trying to make it as short as possible. This question is actually just part $c$ of the entire question. The previous parts were to prove that every square matrix has a Schur decomposition, and that normal + triangular = diagonal. On the exam I would have 30 minutes to write all this.